# How to get a border resource in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

How to get a border resource?

XAML:

```
<Control.Resources>
    <Border x:Key="MyBorder" Margin="10" CornerRadius="4" Background="Black" Width="200" Height="200">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Border Height="100" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                </Border>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="text"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Control.Resources>
```

C# code:

```
Border border=FindResource("MyBorder");
```

I use the FindResource("MyBorder") function, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.Resources["MyBorder"]
```